# Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get the data array as following:

```
$coupons = $user->coupons::where('is_activated_flg', 1)->where('is_used_flg', 0)->lists('amount');
```

I have this error:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be called statically

Could you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the error is not clear but it means `$user->coupons::where` whould be `$user->coupons->where`

Comment: @ash Get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change it into something like this:

```
$couponQuery = $user->coupons()->where('is_activated_flg', 1)->where('is_used_flg', 0);
$couponCollection = $couponQuery->get();
```

..or combined:

```
$coupons = $user->coupons()->where('is_activated_flg', 1)->where('is_used_flg', 0)->get();
```

If you are using Laravel 5.1 or slightly below you might want to consider using pluck instead of lists:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('name');
$plucked->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to send an array of where clauses

from official docs

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status','1'],
    ['subscribed','<>','1'],
])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects

Comment: *IF* the OP is not using Eloquent, this answer isn't actually that bad.  But I assume the OP is using Eloquent.

Comment: God bless  you :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably define an eloquent relationship in my user model.

```
  /**
  * User can have many coupons
  */
  public function coupons()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Coupons')->where('is_activated_flg', 1)->where('is_used_flg', 0);
  }
```

and then call it like

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$coupons = $user->coupons;
```